# How to flush your database using Repo

Tags: database, elixir, phoenix-framework, ex-unit

More specifically I have a Phoenix Application using Ecto and Repo.
I would like to flush my database after running each Exunit test which alters the database.

One way I could accomplish this would be to run all of the `change` functions in the migrations in `priv/repo/migrations/` directory, but I feel that there should be a nicer way.

Perhaps something like running the [flush](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#flush/0) function?

Comment: What does "flush your database" mean?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant removing all data in all tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is already handled for you when running Ecto in sandbox mode, which is the way Phoenix generates the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you would collect these side-effected tests into one file, you could use [setup](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#setup/1) callback, like this:

```
setup do
  for model <- [list modules you want to clear], do: Repo.delete_all(model)
end
```